# Create/Setup spark cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I referred to the spark documentation on apache website - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html

according to the docs

> Run ./spark-ec2 -k  -i  -s  launch , where  is the name of your EC2 key pair (that you gave it when you created it),  is the private key file for your key pair,  is the number of slave nodes to launch (try 1 at first), and  is the name to give to your cluster.

For example:

```
./spark-ec2 --key-pair=awskey --identity-file=awskey.pem --region=us-west-1 --instance-type=<instance-type> --zone=us-west-1a launch my-spark-cluster
```

creates the EC2 instance of type  where default type is m1.large. I can also create the instance with `t2.micro` or any other. But I want a heterogeneous cluster where the master has higher processing power and large storage(like `d2.xlarge`). And slaves instance type should be the default `m1.large`.

How to mention master instance type and slave instance type ??

Comment: You'd rather use the aws emr cli for that purpose. You have more control on your cluster using it and in the end, it's still creating EC2 machines.

Comment: but that doesn't involve automation. i have to dynamically create cluster based on some use case. i have used this command in an automation script. converting it to cli needs a lot of rework.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't involve automation ? I use the aws emr cli in a automated manner.

Comment: I want EC2. Not EMR.

Comment: migrations cost but at least you have access on all the aws API features.